# Foundation 4 showing grid in nav bar

Tags: zurb-foundation

In the Nav Bar docs for Foundation 3 you were able to add a grid within a navigation menu. See http://foundation.zurb.com/old-docs/f3/navigation.php#nav-bar

If I try the same approach in Foundation 4, it doesn't work properly. Here's a screenshot of how it looks.

[image]

```
<li class="has-dropdown"><a href="#">Settings</a>
    <ul class="dropdown">
        <li><label>Dropdown Level 1 Label</label></li>
        <li>
            <div class="row">
               <div class="small-6 columns"><a href="#">hello</a></div>
               <div class="small-6 columns"><a href="#">hello</a></div>
            </div>
       </li>
   </ul>
</li>
```

Have they removed this functionality or am I doing it wrong?